# Synchronizing a variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, synchronization, atomic

I've got a chain reaction of exploding boxes, and I want to keep the surrounding from falling until the reaction is finished, so I have a variable that is incremented each time a box begins to explode and decremented when it is finished exploding. It works for small reactions, but large ones never return the counter to 0, leading me to suspect synchronization issues. However my attempts at synching it have not done anything. What am I doing wrong?

Global method for lock:

```
func lock(handle: AnyObject, body : () -> ()) {
    objc_sync_enter(handle)
    body()
    objc_sync_exit(handle)
}
```

Local method for explode:

```
func explode(x: Int) {
    currently_exploding++
        switch type {
        case 0:
            self.runAction(self.die, completion: { () -> Void in
                lock(currently_exploding) {
                    currently_exploding--
                }
            })
            break;
        case 1:
            self.runAction(self.die, completion: { () -> Void in
                lock(currently_exploding) {
                    let i = self.i
                    let j = self.j
                    if j < 9 {
                        board[i][j+1]?.explode(x+1)
                    }
                    if i < 4 {
                        board[i+1][j]?.explode(x+1)
                    }
                    if j > 0 {
                        board[i][j-1]?.explode(x+1)
                    }
                    if i > 0 {
                        board[i-1][j]?.explode(x+1)
                    }
                    currently_exploding--
                }
            })
            break;
        default:
            println("got to default")
            break;
        }
}
```

The reaction starts by calling explode(1) on one of the boxes. The value of x is just keeping track of the depth of the chain and is not related to the variable I'm trying to synchronize.

Comment: Need more context. In a class? What's the threading model?

Comment: The lock function is in GameScene, just before the class declaration. The explode function is in Box, inside the class declaration. How do I find the threading model? Thanks

Comment: Is it multithread? I guess the explosion always happens in the main queue as it has to update the UI, I think that is a good moment to update your counter as this way you don't need to worry with locks

Comment: Whatever multithreading it's doing is through SpriteKit, so I don't know exactly. I've tried some other ways of synchronizing it that I found examples of online, no luck